# xslt xml html: how can I decode URL by apply xsl template?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, urldecode

I want to have my data decoded after the xsl transfomation, what can I do?

source:

```
<label><![CDATA[%3Clabel%20for%3D%22grp_Jb6dVM%22%20class%3D%22control-label%20span2%22%20%3ETenant%20Name%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22required%22%3E%2A%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Flabel%3E]]></label>
```

the output I want:

```
<label><![CDATA[<label for="grp_Jb6dVM" class="control-label span2" >Tenant Name <span class="required">*</span></label>]]></label>
```

so, how can I write my template to achieve this??

Comment: do you ever write XSL yourself? What did you do before there was StackOverflow?

Comment: I am new to this thing, I wrote my first xsl last day. I dont know if it is wrong to ask questions on stackoverflow, or is there any rules that I cannot ask questions that similar or something? And I asked because no body asks this question before. I'm helping building the stackoverflow database, am I? Can you give me some instructions of using StackOverFlow? I am also new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: Yes, building the StackOverflow database is a good in its own right. I also like that there isn't a RTFM culture here and that people can ask the most basic questions. I guess I just have a personal misgivings about people not even attempting to solve problems on their own.

Comment: I suppose if people are willing to answer, I have no grounds to object, really. It's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: I am reading a xsl book, but I cannot find answer there. and disable-output-escaping="yes" don't do the trick for me. I dont have a stackoverflow account till yesterday because I was always attempting to solve problems on my own. It's just sometimes don't work well. And something is basic to you but maybe not basic to me.  And I'm grateful to all those people who give me help. And I'm willing to answer other people's questions on what I am good at.

Comment: It's fine. I think I am reacting to people who are less gracious than you. I also concede that there is no reason to beat your head against the wall when people are so willing to help. You actually learn faster by asking early.

Answer (score 4):

**xsltproc** contains an extension named decode-uri

```
$ xsltproc --dumpextensions | grep code
{http://exslt.org/strings}encode-uri
{http://exslt.org/strings}decode-uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I deside not to do this in the process of XSL Transformation. In any oo language, it should be no more than 1 line of code to decode it. Like in Java,

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
```